# Does Nymphomaniac Vol. I have real sex scenes?

Tags: nymphomaniac

I have just watched *[Nymphomaniac Vol. I](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1937390/)* (2013). I heard the actors and actresses have real sex scenes. Is that true?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nymphomaniac_%28film%29#Production) concludes that the *actors* (who actually portrayed the characters) **didn't have real sex**:

> To produce scenes of unsimulated sex, von Trier used digital compositing to superimpose the genitals of pornographic film actors onto the bodies of the film's actors. Producer Louise Vesth explained during the Cannes Film Festival:
>
> ***We shot the actors pretending to have sex and then had the body doubles, who really did have sex, and in post [production] we will digital impose the two. So above the waist it will be the star and the below the waist it will be the doubles.***
>
> [Charlotte] Gainsbourg and [Stacy] Martin further revealed that prosthetic vaginae and closed sets were used during filming.

The technique is explained by star Martin in the first video on [this MTV page](http://www.mtv.com/news/1724571/nymphomaniac-sex-scenes/), which further specifies:

> While most the composite footage won’t make it into US theaters, **the uncut version of the sex scenes only featured the midsection of the actors’ porn double.** Everything above or below actually belonged to Martin or [Shia] LaBeouf, for example.
>
> You’d think that removing all spontaneity from a sex scene would kill any believable chemistry, but for “Nymphomaniac” every move had to be carefully predetermined.
>
> “Basically, we would do the scenes,” Martin said. “What happens is that **we have to agree on a position because of the CGI. Everything has to be set, so we would do the scene with Shia or whoever it was, and we would get little black dots on our bodies,”** Martin said. “It was very unerotic, very technical and it gets quite boring because then they have to do exactly the same with the porn doubles. But they’re having real sex, and they put the two together.”